# Method anySatisfy from assertJ swallows actual failure message

Tags: assertj

I use assertJ in my project for nice formulation of test assertions.
I call `anySatisfy` on a collection where I pass assertions in a lambda that must be met for at least one of the collection elements.

```
assertThat(myCollection).anySatisfy(myCollectionElement-> { 
    assertThat(myCollectionElement).callAnyAssertionMethod();
    assertThat(myCollectionElement).anotherAssertionMethod();
}
```

Once no element satisfies the required assertions, `anySatisfy` fails as expected.

The problem is that the console output then as follows

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting any element of:
  <allCollectionElementsArSerializedHere>
to satisfy the given assertions requirements but none did.

at myPackage.myTestClass.myTestMethod(MyTestClass.java:xyz)
```

Concluding I do know that `anySatisfy` being called in line `xyz` failed, but I do not get to know which particular assertions inside the lambda are not met. I only can see that in the debugger.

How can I achieve to get the expected log output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't but we have improved [`allSatisfy`](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1379) to report the unsatisfied requirements.
We will do the same for `anySatisfy` for the next release, I have created https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1400 to track this.

Comment: https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1400 has been addressed, it will be available in 3.12.0 for be release in the next few weeks.